# mysql: is there a way to do a "INSERT INTO" 2 tables?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have one table with 2 columns that i essentially want to split into 2 tables:

table A columns: user_id, col1, col2

New tables:

B: user_id, col1

C: user_id, col2

I want to do:

```
INSERT INTO B (user_id, col1) SELECT user_id,col1 from A;
INSERT INTO C (user_id,col2) SELECT user_id, col2 from A;
```

But i want to do it in one statement. The table is big, so i just want to do it in one pass. Is there a way to do this?

Thx.

Comment: In theory you would create a view V joining B and C then insert into V, the theory being rule 6 of Codd's 12 rules: "The view updating rule: All views that are theoretically updatable must be updatable by the system" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd's_12_rules). The standard workaround is an `INSTEAD OF` trigger but it seems MySQL does not support triggers on `VIEW`s.

Comment: ...in which case you can create a trigger for insert on either B or C where you would place the complementing insert statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't insert into more than one table at the same time. `INSERT` syntax allows only a single table name.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

> INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED |
>   HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] [INTO]
>   **tbl_name** [...

Comment: would it not be considered one statement if Jack were using sub-queries?

Comment: @Josh: this still wouldn't let him insert into two (or more) tables

Answer (score 1):

Write a stored procedure to encapsulate the two inserts and protect the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

If by "in one statement", you mean "atomically" - so that it can never happen that it's inserted into one table but not the other - then transactions are what you're looking for:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO B (user_id, col1) SELECT user_id,col1 from A;
INSERT INTO C (user_id,col2) SELECT user_id, col2 from A;
COMMIT;
```

If you need to actually do this in a single statement, you could create these as a stored procedure and call that, as [@lexu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859774/mysql-is-there-a-way-to-do-a-insert-into-2-tables/4859806#4859806) suggests.

See the manual for reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

Caveat: this will not work with MyISAM tables (no transaction support), they need to be InnoDB.

Comment: Maybe I'm off, but I consider anything contained by one semicolon to be a statement (like an expression), is there a better definition?

Comment: @Josh: You are quite correct - see my explanation in the first sentence. In my experience, many people mean "so that it happens atomically" when they say "in one statement", as they're not aware of transactions. If, indeed, the OP means "must be done in a single statement", then my answer is not applicable. (I'm aware that the OP *wrote* that, but people here often *mean* different things than they write, e.g. because they're still learning the relevant vocabulary.)

Comment: Yes, i did mean "one statement" and not "atomically". The intent is performance; i'm guessing (and i could be wrong) that one pass through this table, selecting the whole row, and then inserting into the 2 new tables is faster than executing the 2 stmts in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your tables are spread over multiple physical disks, then the speed of the select/insert is likely to be IO bound.

Trying to insert into two tables at once (even if it were possible) is likely to increase the total insert time as the disk will have to thrash more writing to your tables.